# How to pass HTTP response object part of node js passport module based authentication callback function?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passport module to write local authentication. Recently I started setting userid after successful authentication as header using response object. Surprisingly I realized that my passport code is not taking HTTP "response" object. Following are details.

Code which doesn't work (callback function is only expecting four parameter):

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function (req, res, username, password, done) {
        log.debug("passport authenticateUser >> req >>"+req+", res >>"+res+", username "+username+", password "+password);
        userService.authenticateUser(req, res, username, password, done);
    }));
```

Code which works

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function (req, username, password, done) {
    log.debug("passport authenticateUser >> req >>"+req+", res >>"+res+", username "+username+", password "+password);
    userService.authenticateUser(req, username, password, done);
}));
```

I need  HTTP "response" object as well. Please help

Comment: The answer means `...+", res >>"+res+"...` should change to `...+", res >>"+req.res+"...`.

Comment: `req.res` how it's possible?....for me it's giving syntax error as `DOT should be replaced by semicolon`.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the response object through `req` as `req.res`.

However, I don't think it's what you want, because your local strategy will only be called for your "login" route; any other routes that a logged-in user will access will not call it, and hence your header won't be set.

Instead, you can use a custom middleware to set the header for each request that a logged-in user makes:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    // Set the X-User-Id header to contain the user id. Obviously
    // you should change this example to fit your situation.
    res.set('X-User-Id', req.user.id);
  }
  next();
});
```

Make sure to add this route *after* `app.use(passport.session())` but *before* any regular routes.

Answer (score 2):

Change the parameter(res) of the following function to (req.res)

Your code->

```
    function (req, ***res***, username, password, done) { 
       log.debug("passport authenticateUser >> req >>"+req+", res >>"+res+",
       username "+username+", password "+password);  
       userService.authenticateUser(req, res, username, password, done); 
    }));
```

After modifying the parameter ->

```
    function (req, ***req.res***, username, password, done) { 
       log.debug("passport authenticateUser >> req >>"+req+", res >>"+res+",
       username "+username+", password "+password);  
       userService.authenticateUser(req, res, username, password, done); 
    }));
```